# Sql server function for displaying word frequency in a column

Tags: sql-server, string, text, indexing, frequency

I have a table that lists a freet text input from a survey where enterents were allowed to enter their responses (regarding colours they would like to have in their wedding)

I would like to write a sql function that gathers all the information from this column, and orders counts the frequency of each word, ordering the result set by this count.

```
Response
--------
Red and White
green
White and blue
Blue
Dark blue
```

I would like the above table to be ordered as follows

```
Response  Frequency
--------  ---------
Blue      3
White     2
And       2
Red       1
Green     1
```

I can strip all the rubbish words like "and" after the function has run. Does anyone know any good functions that produce this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay this works a treat. Firstly a function to separate the values...

```
Alter Function dbo.SeparateValues    

(    
 @data VARCHAR(MAX),    
 @delimiter VARCHAR(10)     
)     
RETURNS     
@tbldata TABLE(col VARCHAR(MAX))    
As    
--Declare @data VARCHAR(MAX) ,@delimiter VARCHAR(10)     
--Declare @tbldata TABLE(col VARCHAR(10))    
--Set @data = 'hello,how,are,you?,234234'    
--Set @delimiter = ','    
--DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col VARCHAR(10))    
Begin    
DECLARE @pos INT    
DECLARE @prevpos INT    
SET @pos = 1     
SET @prevpos = 0    

WHILE @pos > 0     
BEGIN    
SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @data, @prevpos+1)    
if @pos > 0     
INSERT INTO @tbldata(col) VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@data, @prevpos+1, @pos-@prevpos-1))))    
else    
INSERT INTO @tbldata(col) VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@data, @prevpos+1, len(@data)-@prevpos))))    
SET @prevpos = @pos     
End    

RETURN       
END
```

then I just apply it to my table...

```
Select Count(*), sep.Col FROM (
        Select * FROM (
            Select value = Upper(RTrim(LTrim(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(response, ',', ' '), '.', ' '), '!', ' '), '+', ' '), ':', ' '), '-', ' '), ';', ' '), '(', ' '), ')', ' '), '/', ' '), '&', ''), '?', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' ')))) FROM Responses
        ) easyValues
        Where value <> '' 
    ) actualValues 
    Cross Apply dbo.SeparateValues(value, ' ') sep
    Group By sep.Col
    Order By Count(*) Desc
```

Okay, so I went OTT with my nested tables, but I've stripped out all the crap characters, separated the values and kept a running total of the most frequently used words.

Comment: The performance of this is probably terrible with the many replace operations and the very slow SeparateValues function. Try using something like this for the string splitting at least: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/04/28/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @phrases TABLE (id int, phrase varchar(max))
INSERT @phrases values
(1,'Red and White'  ),
(2,'green'          ),
(3,'White and blue' ),
(4,'Blue'           ),
(5,'Dark blue'      );

SELECT word, COUNT(*) c
FROM @phrases
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(phrase,' ','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS xml) xml1 ) t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT n.value('.','varchar(max)') AS word FROM xml1.nodes('a') x(n) ) t2
GROUP BY word
```

> ```
> word         freq
> ----------- -----------
> and         2
> blue        3
> Dark        1
> green       1
> Red         1
> White       2
> ```

Comment: very nice - and no UDF needed!

Answer (score 1):

You're main problem is that you're missing a split function in SQL Server.

Theres a sample one here that looks pretty good..

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648

Using that, you write a stored proc along the lines of...

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (Response nvarchar(50), Frequency int) 

DECLARE @response nvarchar(100)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT response FROM YourTable

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @response 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       /* Pseudo Code */ 
       --Split @Response 
       --Iterate through each word in returned list
       --IF(EXISTS in #TEMP)
       --    UPDATE THAT ROW & INCREMENT THE FREQUENCY
       --ELSE
       --    NEW WORD, INSERT TO #Temp WITH A FREQUENCY OF 1

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @response 
END   

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Theres probably a less fugly way to do this without cursors, but if it's just something you
need to run once, and you're table or Responses isn't phenomenally large, then this should work

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned - I refuse cursours, i'll look at making it CTE!

Comment: If you're on SQL 2005 or 2008, you could also look at writing this as a CLR Function in .NET, the spliting/iterating/counting would probably be alot easier in a .NET language