# SQL Query to get count of words in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which have schema like this

```
id name

1 jack
2 jack of eden
3 eden of uk
4 m of s
```

I want to execute a query which gives me count of words like this

```
count word
2 jack
2 eden
3 of
```

this means jack has been here 2 times, eden 2 times and of has been 3 times.

Hope you got the question, m trying too but not getting the right query or approach to it

thnx

Comment: I should automatically show words which has occurrence more than 1

Comment: same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881913/sql-server-function-for-displaying-word-frequency-in-a-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table is named `temp` (probably not - change it to the right name of your table)

I used a subquery for finding all the words in your table:

```
select distinct regexp_substr(t.name, '[^ ]+',1,level) word , t.name, t.id
     from temp t
     connect by level <= regexp_count(t.name, ' ') + 1
```

this query splits all the words from all records. I aliased it `words`.
Then I joined it with your table (in the query it's called temp) and counted the number of occurences in every record.

```
select words.word, count(regexp_count(tt.name, words.word))
from(
select distinct regexp_substr(t.name, '[^ ]+',1,level) word , t.name, t.id
 from temp t
 connect by level <= regexp_count(t.name, ' ') + 1) words, temp tt
 where words.id= tt.id
 group by words.word
```

You can also add:

```
having count(regexp_count(tt.name, words.word)) > 1
```

---

**update**: for better performance we can replace the inner subquery with the results of a pipelined function:
first, create a schema type and a table of it:

```
create or replace type t is object(word varchar2(100), pk number);
/
create or replace type t_tab as table of t;
/
```

then create the function:

```
create or replace function split_string(del in varchar2) return t_tab
  pipelined is

  word    varchar2(4000);
  str_t   varchar2(4000) ;
  v_del_i number;
  iid     number;

  cursor c is
    select * from temp; -- change  to your table

begin

  for r in c loop
    str_t := r.name;
    iid   := r.id;

    while str_t is not null loop

      v_del_i := instr(str_t, del, 1, 1);

      if v_del_i = 0 then
        word  := str_t;
        str_t := '';
      else
        word  := substr(str_t, 1, v_del_i - 1);
        str_t := substr(str_t, v_del_i + 1);
      end if;

      pipe row(t(word, iid));

    end loop;

  end loop;

  return;
end split_string;
```

now the query should look like:

```
select words.word, count(regexp_count(tt.name, words.word))
from(
select word, pk as id from table(split_string(' '))) words, temp tt
 where words.id= tt.id
 group by words.word
```

Comment: ok with Oracle 11g, but older versions don't come with REGEXP_COUNT. Otherwise: `CONNECT BY length(regexp_susbstr(name, '[^ ]+',1,level)) >= 1`

Comment: This is how I named your table in my test case :)

Comment: this is how I aliased the subquery that gives all the words, I'll add some explanation in my answer

Comment: @A.B.Cade the query is not responding.. my table has >800 rows

Comment: @A.B.Cade ur subquery taking very high time to respond.. any optimization we can do in it.. :) thnx