# SQL Update Query running forever. Oracle Performace Tuning Tips required

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-update, self-join

I have a table which has 9 million records. The requirement is as below :
1. Table is inserted with 9 million records. Each entry will have a rowid which is inserted into table using trigger.
2. we have two columns which has to be updated seperately in the same table called First_Insatance and First_Instance_Date.
3. These First Instance columns should hold the first Rowid number of the duplicate records present in the table.

we are using the below code to update

```
  UPDATE TABLE_A T4
      SET (T4.ROW_ID_FIRST_INS, T4.ROW_ID_DT_FIRST_INS) =
             (  SELECT MIN (T3.ROW_ID), MIN (T3.UPDATE_DATE)
                  FROM TABLE_A T3
                 WHERE     T3.SOURCE(+) = T4.SOURCE
                       AND    SUBSTR (T3.TABLE_NAME,
                                      1,
                                      REGEXP_INSTR (T3.TABLE_NAME,
                                                    '\_[0-9]{8}T',
                                                    1,
                                                    1,
                                                    0))
                           || SUBSTR (T3.TABLE_NAME,
                                      REGEXP_INSTR (T3.TABLE_NAME,
                                                    '\_[0-9]{8}T',
                                                    1,
                                                    1,
                                                    1),
                                        LENGTH (T3.TABLE_NAME)
                                      - REGEXP_INSTR (T3.TABLE_NAME,
                                                      '\_[0-9]{8}T',
                                                      1,
                                                      1,
                                                      1)) =
                                 SUBSTR (T4.TABLE_NAME,
                                         1,
                                         REGEXP_INSTR (T4.TABLE_NAME,
                                                       '\_[0-9]{8}T',
                                                       1,
                                                       1,
                                                       0))
                              || SUBSTR (T4.TABLE_NAME,
                                         REGEXP_INSTR (T4.TABLE_NAME,
                                                       '\_[0-9]{8}T',
                                                       1,
                                                       1,
                                                       1),
                                           LENGTH (T4.TABLE_NAME)
                                         - REGEXP_INSTR (T4.TABLE_NAME,
                                                        '\_[0-9]{8}T',
                                                         1,
                                                         1,
                                                         1))
                       AND NVL (T4.I_NAM, 'xx') =
                              NVL (T3.I_NAM, 'xx')
                       AND NVL (T4.J_NAM, 'xx') = NVL (T3.J_NAM, 'xx')
                       AND NVL (T4.SYS_NAM, 'xx') =
                              NVL (T3.SYS_NAM, 'xx')
                       AND NVL (T4.TG_TAB_NAM, 'xx') =
                              NVL (T3.TG_TAB_NAM, 'xx')
                       AND NVL (T4.PK, 'xx') = NVL (T3.PK, 'xx')
                       AND NVL (T4.ERR, 'xx') =
                              NVL (T3.ERR, 'xx')
                       AND NVL (T4.VAL, 'xx') =
                              NVL (T3.VAL, 'xx')
                       AND NVL (T4.ID, 'xx') = NVL (T3.ID, 'xx')
              GROUP BY T4.FIELD,
                       T4.ERR,
                       T4.VAL,
                       T4.ID,
                       T4.PK,
                       T4.I_NAM,
                       T4.SYS_NAM,
                       T4.J_NAM)
    WHERE T4.CURRENT_LOAD_ID = some number FROM CURSOR;
```

The query is taking 35 secs for 3050 records, but when run for 4L records. Its not stopping and running from past 2 days.

Row_ID is PK and have created NU index on all group by columns except few which had size 4000.

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked for other locks on the table?

Comment: Yeah. There are no locks. I generated the explain plan for this but the Cost is extremely high..It more than a Million.

Comment: If I were you, I would trace the session and see what happens.

Comment: BTW, if recommendable to use only ROWID as primary key because the ROWID could change when such statements are executed: alter table t shrink space compact,  alter table t move, flashback table t to ...

Comment: Actually its not ROWID but a sequence that is inserted by a trigger. Looks similar to Rowid. We have to group the record and update the first value of it for each group. We have a DBA Team monitoring the Job though.

Comment: I think your REGEXP_INSTR may be the culprit. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106247/oracle-query-slow-with-regexp-substraggregator-1-level](This) suggests we may gain performance from utilizing a pipeline table.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an overly complex method of determining duplicates using aliases.
I'd try to integrate something more simple along these lines.
select id 
from
table1
group by
id having count(id ) > 1

Without your table structure, some sample data, and a full explanation of the problem it is hard to do  more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can provide you a sample data :

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can provide you a sample data :
row_id    col1    col2    col3    date    first_ins    first_ins_dt
1    A    B    C    sysdate    1    SYSDATE
2    E    F    G    SYSDATE    2    SYSDATE
3    A    B    C    SYSDATE+1  1    SYSDATE
4    A    B    C    SYSDATE+2  1    SYSDATE
5    H    I    J    SYSDATE+2  5    SYSDATE+2

In the above data you can see first instance and first instance column has the first rowid and date everywhere where the data is repeated. This is something i need to achieve for a very high amount of data.