# Create table of counts for characters from table of strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Say I have a table of text responses:

```
ID   Responses  
1    Sample response goes here!!  
2    Another sample here...  
3    & another one here too! :)
```

What's the best way to return a table like the following:

```
Character   Count
!           3
&           1
:           1
.           3
a           4
s           5
char(10)    0

... (and so forth)
```

Do I have to create a table of ALL possible SQL characters then iterate through the set of text responses? If so, where can I find a list of all possible SQL characters? (including special characters like "char(10)")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881913/sql-server-function-for-displaying-word-frequency-in-a-column

Comment: @GoatCO I added a new answer to that question

Answer (score 1):

No you don't. The lists exist and they are huge. I won't point you at them because you don't need them. You could either create the table, then parse your strings one character at a time and "upsert" the database for each character. Or you could process the strings one row at a time and populate an array indexed by the character.  Once the strings are fully parsed, walk the array and upsert the db with the counts in the array.

upsert is pseudo code meaning "see if the row exists, if it does, update it, if it does not, insert it".

Some databases support a way to do an upsert in one statement but most do not and you have to code three statements and an if.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to count ASCII characters only, or also Unicode characters?  If it's the former, I would make a table that looked something like this...

```
    CREATE TABLE CharCounts
    (CharID int not null,
    CharCount bigint not null)
```

The first column would hold the ASCII code of the char (see the [ASCII](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx) function in t-sql).  The second column would hold the actual count.  You could then write a stored procedure that would leverage the various string functions in t-sql (ASCII, LEN, SUBSTRING) to calculate the counts.

Answer (score 0):

If the max length of each response is small, this works pretty well. If you are dealing with varchar(max) and huge strings, SQL is probably not the best tool to use.

```
;WITH num AS (SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) i FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT
  ASCII(SUBSTRING(Response,i,1)) AS Character,
  COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Responses
INNER JOIN num ON ASCII(SUBSTRING(Response,i,1)) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ASCII(SUBSTRING(Response,i,1))
ORDER BY ASCII(SUBSTRING(Response,i,1))
```