# How to return list of duplicate words and the count of instances in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I basically have a table with a column. Lets call the column 'Summary'

So if 'Summary' looks like this. I went to the park to find a dog. The dog was not there. I left because there was no dog.

I want to be able to return a list that basically gives me the duplicate words and the hit count of how many times it appeared. I won't know which word exactly is a duplicate so I cannot hard code it into the SQL query.

I need the results to be "Dog" -3, "The"- 2, "I"- 2

I cant post images so I cannot post a table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881913/sql-server-function-for-displaying-word-frequency-in-a-column/21945152#21945152

Comment: I think the answer from martin is correct.  If you are going to be doing a lot of word analysis then you may want to parse the words out into a separate table.

Comment: Ok I will look into that

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a very efficient way of achieving the result you are looking for, but this will output a list of words that have a count of 2 or more in the specified `summary`:

```
DECLARE @summary NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @summary = N'I went to the park to find a dog. The dog was not there. I left because there was no dog.'

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @PosA   INT
DECLARE @Word   NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- A temporary table to hold matches
CREATE TABLE dbo.#WordList
(
    Word        NVARCHAR(MAX),
    WordCount   INT
)

SET @PosA = 0
WHILE (LEN(@summary) > 0)
BEGIN
    -- Find the position of the word end
    SET @PosA = CHARINDEX(' ', @summary)
    IF (@PosA = 0)
        SET @PosA = LEN(@summary) + 1

    -- Extract the word and shorten the summary text
    SET @Word = SUBSTRING(@summary, 0, @PosA)
    IF (@PosA < LEN(@summary))
        SET @summary = SUBSTRING(@summary, @PosA + 1, LEN(@summary) - @PosA)
    ELSE
        SET @summary = ''

    -- Strip punctuation
    SET @Word = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Word, '.', ''), ',', '')

    -- Add or create the word
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.#WordList WHERE Word = @Word)
        UPDATE  dbo.#WordList
          SET   WordCount = WordCount + 1
          WHERE (Word = @Word)
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO dbo.#WordList (Word, WordCount)
          VALUES (@Word, 1)
END

-- Get results
SELECT  *
  FROM  dbo.#WordList
  WHERE (WordCount > 1)
  ORDER BY Word

--- Tidy up
DROP TABLE dbo.#WordList
```

Effectively, split the summary text by each space and then remove punctuation from the resulting word.  The resulting words are stored in the `#WordList` temporary table, with the count incremented as appropriate.

Finally the results are returned at the end.

Note that you may wish to improve the punctuation removal as I only added full-stops and commas for the purposes of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for each row, you'll need to split the summary column into separate rows.  Then you can do select on that result set, counting each value.  Here's a link to a bunch of nice Split functions:
[Split functions](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648)

They are pretty old, but still very effective.   I think something like tvf should get you going:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @summaries TABLE (id int, summary nvarchar(max))
INSERT @summaries values
  (1,N'I went to the park to find a dog. The dog was not there. I left because there was no dog.')

SELECT id, word, COUNT(*) c
FROM @summaries
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(summary,' ','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS xml) xml1 ) t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT n.value('.','varchar(max)') AS word FROM xml1.nodes('a') x(n) ) t2
GROUP BY id, word
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```